# Modifying PHP function to redirect after action

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'd like the following PHP code to redirect to a specified page after completion of the function. I tried a few different methods but it doesn't ever seem to do anything. The current action that this is taking is that after the button to call the function is pressed, it redirects to an empty page. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    function quote_upvote_button($quoteid, $canvote, $ajaxy=FALSE)
    {
        $s = ' class="quote_plus" id="quote_plus_'.$quoteid.'"';
        if (!$canvote) {
            $url = '<a href="?'.urlargs('vote',$quoteid,'plus').'" '.$s.' title="'.lang('upvote').'">+</a>';
                if ($ajaxy) {
                    return '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(\'<a href="javascript:ajax_vote('.$quoteid.',1);" '.$s.' title="'.lang('upvote').'">+</a>\');
                    </script><noscript>'.$url.'</noscript>';
        }
        return $url;
    }
    return '<span '.$s.' title="'.lang('cannot_vote_'.$canvote).'">+</span>';
}
```

Comment: What page do you want it to redirect too?

Comment: Try `href="javascript:ajax_vote(1,1);location.href='google.com';void(0);"`

Comment: You are looking for a header redirection (PHP) or a window.location  change (JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, `$your_redirect_url` is the location it will go to. It can either be in relative (/foo/bar) or fully qualified (http://foo.com/bar) formats. You can read more on [PHP Header Redirects  here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Please be aware that Miinimals answer requires an additional PECL library to execute, where this is an ingrain function.

```
function quote_upvote_button($quoteid, $canvote, $ajaxy = false, $your_redirect_url = '/')
{
    $s = ' class="quote_plus" id="quote_plus_'.$quoteid.'"';
    if (!$canvote) {
        $url = '<a href="?'.urlargs('vote',$quoteid,'plus').'" '.$s.' title="'.lang('upvote').'">+</a>';
        if ($ajaxy) 
        {
            // Redirect to your location, and terminate...
            // Will redirect to root on default, or can be overridden/modified as an arg
            header("Location: $your_redirect_url");
            exit;
        }
        return $url;
    }
    return '<span '.$s.' title="'.lang('cannot_vote_'.$canvote).'">+</span>';
}
```

Comment: You should not make this redirect, if you can just to pass control to other php code(which you want to call after redirect) in place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the http_redirect documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

The redirect should go before the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You first find the url then redirect to that url by

```
   header('location:'.$url);
```

or in js u can use

```
   window.location.assign($url)
   window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
```